# How do I launch a Chrome-dev-app in commandline?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, google-chrome-extension

I'm using the Chrome Dev IDE to create chrome apps. As usual clicking the 'Run' triangle button top left of the ide launches your html5 chrome app.

I assume the chrome ide is using some command to launch this.
How do I run this chrome app just as well from command line?

Basically, I want to be able to use my webstorm IDE as it has better HTML5 development tools, and I'm tired of having to make changes in this and then switch to the barebones chrome ide to launch my app.

Comment: It uses [developerPrivate](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/developerPrivate) and [management](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management)

Comment: @DanielHerr Thanks for the info, but unfortunately I'm still not sure how this answers my question. How do either help me launch my developed apps from webstorm or command line without having to launch them on the Google Chrome Editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *launch* an installed app by its `id`.

Assuming `google-chrome` is the command to launch Chrome on your system and app's id is `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`, the following launches your app:

```
google-chrome --app-id=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

The bigger problem you have is *reloading* the app after making changes - if you just launch it after it was already loaded into Chrome as unpacked, some changes won't apply leading to an inconsistent state. You can't directly do that with command line (which is probably good for security reasons).

You can achieve external control over this, but it's going to involve extra moving parts.

1. You will need a helper extension using [`chrome.management` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management). It can force a reload by disabling and enabling an unpacked extension/app (and launch one as well).
2. You will need some way to trigger the extension to do that. Many approaches exist, including but not limited to:

   - [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)
   - WebSockets (see [GhostText](https://github.com/Cacodaimon/GhostText-for-SublimeText) as a sample)
   - Intercepting a specific URL (see [Chrome Extensions Reloader](https://github.com/arikw/chrome-extensions-reloader) as a sample)

   The last option is probably the best one for you - since you can simply call Chrome with that URL through command line to trigger it:

   ```
   google-chrome http://reload.extensions/
   ```

   My advice is to take the Reloader and adapt it for your case.